# Create a file from a path, creating subdirectories if they not exists

Tags: .net, file

In config of my app I've a path, for example "logs\updater\updater.log"

Starting the app, I want to create the file updater.log, creating all subfolders if they not exists.

So, if tomorrow my user changes the path in config to "logs\mypathisbetter\updater.log", my app continues to work, writing log to the new file.

`File.Create`, `FileInfo.Create`, `Streamwriter.Create` or so: they do that?

Or do I need to check if folders exists, before?

I can't find a clear answer to this question on the net.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved using a little bit of code:

```
private static void EnsureDirectoryExists(string filePath) 
{ 
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
  if (!fi.Directory.Exists) 
  { 
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fi.DirectoryName); 
  } 
}
```

Sorry for this really newbie post...
Thank you all! :-)

Comment: Your approach is grate for modulising the script

Answer (score 12):

No, they don't seem to - you'll get a DirectoryNotFoundException, I believe from all three.

You need to do something like a `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` first.

**EDIT**:

For a bit more of a full solution which starts with a path including filename, try:

```
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath);
    writer.WriteLine("hello mum");
    writer.Close();
```

But bear in mind you'll need some error handling too, so that the writer always gets closed (in a 'finally' block).

Comment: In fact, I tried too.
There's a "Best Practice" to do that work?
Some ideas? :-)

Comment: Solved using a little bit of code:
  private static void CreateFile(string filePath)
  {
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
   if (!fi.Directory.Exists)
   {
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fi.DirectoryName);
   }
  }

Comment: You can't really do it in a comment.  Either edit your question to include it or, if it's an answer, you can always answer your own question and put it in there.  (See here for how to format questions & answers: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 6):

Another option if just want to create a folder/directory if it does not exist is to simply do this in C#:

```
// using System.IO;
if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
}
```

Comment: Will this create sub-directories needed for the path too?

Comment: Yes, it will create sub-directories as well